# SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

My problem is I’m going to create a SQL stored procedure so that I can create a report based from the stored procedure.

Question: How will I be able to display the records in the following sequence?

```
ABCON                       
67890      2/1/2012                     
123        2/10/2012                    
456        3/10/2012                    
789        3/11/2012                    
DEFON                           
222        3/12/2012                    
333        3/18/2012                    
GHION                               
67890      4/1/2012                     
444        5/1/2012                     
555        5/15/2012                    
789        06/11/2012
```

Given sample table:

```
  Column1   Column2   Column3   ColDate  
  ABCON     67890               02/01/2012  
              123      67890    02/10/2012   
              456        123    03/10/2012   
  DEFON       222           03/12/2012  
              333        222     3/18/2012    
  GHION     67890               04/01/2012   
              444     67890     05/01/2012   
              555       444      5/15/2012   
              789       456     06/11/2012
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!  That way, you don't need any of the messy `&nbsp;` or `<br>` tags

Answer (score 2):

This code should work.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2,Column2, ColDate
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ColDate ASC
```

**NOTE:**
To display the data in the report like this
you need to use the `GROUP` function in what report are you using

```
 ABCON                       
    67890      2/1/2012                     
    123        2/10/2012                    
    456        3/10/2012                    
    789        3/11/2012                    
    DEFON                           
    222        3/12/2012                    
    333        3/18/2012                    
    GHION                               
    67890      4/1/2012                     
    444        5/1/2012                     
    555        5/15/2012                    
    789        06/11/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, ColDate
FROM sampletable
ORDER BY ColDate ASC
```